# Jquery cannot get value from each function

Tags: jquery

I am using tables with input fields in them.
I am trying to get the value from set of input fields with same class and compare to each of its adjacent input with diffrent class name.
I can see the value in the input but the value is returned empty by jquery.

```
$('.subtotal').each(function(){
        var price = $(this).parent().parent().find('td input.price');
        console.log(price.val());
 });
```

Here is the html. these rows will be repeated.

```
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="data[<?=$i?>][title]" class="title"/>
                        <ul class="order_search_title">

                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="data[<?=$i?>][author]" class="author"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="data[<?=$i?>][isbn]" class="isbn"/>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select hidden="hidden" name="data[<?=$i?>][qty]" id="" class="qty">

                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number"  name="data[<?=$i?>][price]" class="price" READONLY />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="data[<?=$i?>][subtotal]" class="subtotal" READONLY/>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="cleartext">clear</a> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img class="delete" src="<?=base_url()?>/imgs/delete25.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: What's `pr.val()`? I guess that's the issue.

Comment: Should `pr.val()` be `price.val()`?

Comment: sorry for typo both are price only, still same result

Comment: Post your HTML and a jsFiddle

Comment: `price.val()` will return only first element value of matched set `td input.price`, just saying...

Comment: i used firebug to test the selector. its good but returning empty string

Comment: posted html to question

Answer (score 0):

You're using the incorrect variable. Use price instead of pr

```
$('.subtotal').each(function(){
        var price = $(this).parent().parent().find('td input.price');
        console.log(price.val()); //This should be price not pr
 });
```

Comment: sorry for typo, both are price only, still same result

Comment: i used firebug to test the selector. its good but returning empty string

Comment: can you paste html snippet

Comment: posted html to question

Comment: Do you have a table tag?