# Jquery returns empty value

Tags: jquery

I am using tables with input fields in them.
I am trying to get the value from set of input fields with same class and compare to each of its adjacent input with diffrent class name.
I can see the value in the input but the value is returned empty by jquery.

```
$('.subtotal').each(function(){
        var price = $(this).parent().parent().find('td input.price');
        console.log(price.val());
 });
```

Here is the html. these rows will be repeated.

```
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="data[<?=$i?>][title]" class="title"/>
                        <ul class="order_search_title">

                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="data[<?=$i?>][author]" class="author"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="data[<?=$i?>][isbn]" class="isbn"/>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select hidden="hidden" name="data[<?=$i?>][qty]" id="" class="qty">

                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number"  name="data[<?=$i?>][price]" class="price" READONLY />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="data[<?=$i?>][subtotal]" class="subtotal" READONLY/>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="cleartext">clear</a> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img class="delete" src="<?=base_url()?>/imgs/delete25.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: How's this different from your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488295/jquery-cannot-get-value-from-each-function

Comment: I haved added html part. nobody bothered it, so reposted it.

Comment: You should give it a little more time, plus re-posting because you're not happy with the attention the other question didn't get isn't allowed.

Comment: its not returning anything because you are actually getting the `val()` of that input where there no value given as its `readOnly` or maybe you want to get the `name` attributes value? check this fiddle for reference http://jsfiddle.net/K4e73/

Comment: those values are added by ajax calls. after that i am trying to get its value

Comment: the value definitely looks empty to me. did you give the ajax request time to complete?

Comment: no it all happends in the same event. But if i try to get the value from outside the each function i could get the values, still in same event.

Comment: Kevin you are right. I have to give ajax to complete. But how to that with single event.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few issues but primarily you need the `<table></table>` tag around your html in order for the find command to find the **td** tag.

Also you have no value in your price as you have it read only, but if you preset a value you can see that it works. Here is a working example of your code with the proper fixes.
http://jsfiddle.net/9pULF/

Comment: those values are added by ajax calls. after that i am trying to get its value

Comment: It should be your table tags in that case. Make sure they are around your table html.